# why error.tsx does't work when throw an error in pages with Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js13

my project structure like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGEc6.png)
nextJs version 13.5.3

```js
// error.tsx
"use client"; // Error components must be Client Components

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Error({
  error,
  reset,
}: {
  error: Error & { digest?: string };
  reset: () => void;
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Log the error to an error reporting service
  }, [error]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Something went wrong!</h2>
      <button
        onClick={
          // Attempt to recover by trying to re-render the segment
          () => reset()
        }
      >
        Try again
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
// about.tsx

import Link from "next/link";

const About = () => {
  throw new Error("error");

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>About</h3>
      <Link href="/">Go to Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```

Do not show UI in error.tsx as my expected.

but If I change the `About` page  to an `async`  component it works

```
const About = async () => {
  throw new Error("error");

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>About</h3>
      <Link href="/">Go to Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the node version is lower than 18.17 
https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation

After upgrade the node, the problems is solved